# Equivalent characterizations of inscribed rectangle in convex region

Tags: calculus, convex-geometry

Note 1 in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450727/planar-convex-region-with-maximum-inner-rectangle-and-outer-rectangle-angle-diff) seems to suggest the maximal area inscribed rectangle in a planar convex region is also the maximal perimeter rectangle in convex shape. I am not entirely convinced this is always the case so I am asking for help in making a formal argument for it. Both area and perimeter are functions of the lengths of the sides of the rectangle, so it seems like a reasonable statement. How to find out a counterexample or show both characterize the same object?

Comment: There is nothing in the MO question which implies that the inscribed rectangle of maximum area is the same as the inscribed angle of maximum perimeter. For a counterexample consider the inscribed rectangle of maximum area inscribed in a semicircle of radius 1 and the inscribed rectangle of maximum perimeter in the same semicircle.